# Mocking filter parameter of sqlalchemy and pytest patching

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

I want to write a test cases to mock filter() for sqlalchemy .using session here to fire a query on the Object .Session is being created in config file .I am able to mock the session.query(FleetEquipment) but how can i mock the filter parameter as well .

```
def get_fleet_equipment_from_thirdparty(self, unit_address, thirdparty_company_id):
            result = session.query(FleetEquipment).filter(
                FleetEquipment.ThirdPartyUnitNumber == unit_address
                and FleetEquipment.ThirdPartyCompanyID == thirdparty_company_id)[:]
```

way i am mocking the session.query paramater is

```
@patch("dao.db_config.session.query",fleetEquipmentMock)
```

and this is how i am creating this mock object

```
fleetEquipment = FleetEquipment(1,123,3,1,1,1)
fleetEquipmentMock = Mock()
fleetEquipmentMock.return_value = fleetEquipment
```

how can i achieve the same .

if i try to mock everything together like

```
@patch("dao.db_config.session.query.filter",fleetEquipmentMock)
```

following exception is observed :

```
AttributeError: <bound method Session.query of <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x00000239F059E198>> does not have the attribute 'filter'
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i did is  :

```
mock = MagicMock(name="mock")
@patch('dao.db_config.session.query',return_value=mock)
def get_fleet_equipment_from_thirdparty_test(self):
    mock.filter.return_value=MagicMock(name="filter")
    assert None==FleetEquipmentService.get_fleet_equipment_from_thirdparty(None,'123',3)
get_fleet_equipment_from_thirdparty_test()
```

But it be improved/refactored more .please let me know your thoughts .Will update once i refine it more.